# Converting a string to a 10-digit integer in Java

Tags: java, string, integer, digit

I have this assignment which should check whether a Triangle is Isosceles, Scalene, Equilateral, Right-Angled.

I am required to use only integers which are less or equal to 2,147,483,647 (or 2^31-1 in other words). I am obliged to use Linux and its Terminal to enter values and get results.

There is no problem with the output when I enter 1 to 9-digit integers, but if I want to conduct a test with a 10-digit integers such as 2^31-1, then I get a result which is not appropriate...

Here is a fragment of my code:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    int a,b,c;
    a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    c = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
}
```

Could anyone suggest me how to deal with this issue?

Comment: what is your input and output?

Comment: did you think about long? and if the input > 2^31, print error msg?

Comment: I think long is the way to go ahead, just to avoid integer overflows

Comment: he is required to use integer only folks!

Comment: Is it the integer creating the problem or the calculation steps that follow? I doubt it is the second case

Comment: there is nothing wrong with your code it seems. I think you have some problem in handling data after you are parsing it.

Comment: Can you put here the input and the bad results and your entire code ?

Comment: Sorry, I can't put the entire code due to a policy issue. Input: 3 times 2147483647 as it is a triangle. Expected output: Equilateral. Actual output: "Such a triangle cannot exist" which is obviously a message which should be printed if I have something different from (a+b>c && a+c>b && b+c>a && a>0 && b>0 && c>0)... I'm allowed to use integers only.

Comment: You cannot use integers and add two MAXINTs and if your teacher asked you to solve it, it is either a trick question or he knows nothing about integer overflows

Comment: Unfortunately, that isn't the case... Whenever I type a 10-digit integer (no matter whether it is the first, second or third argument), I get the "Such a triangle cannot exist" error.

Comment: for the arithmetic part, check it out: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/NUM00-J.+Detect+or+prevent+integer+overflow,  for the input validation it is easy, check the size of String, larger than 10 throw error. equal to 10 , do string comparison to 2,147,483,647

Comment: @Warditive please check the edit I've made to my answer. I think it solves your "tell me the type of triangle" problem

Comment: Michael, thanks for the good suggestion. However, the problem still persists... Isn't there a simpler way to solve it?

Comment: Okay, isn't there a way to put a restriction on top of my program like in C - define <largest integer> = 2^31-1. If so, how to do it in Java (I am a novice)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know.. but I tried running your code, with BASH + JAVA and I don't see any  problem with the output.

Here is the screenshot.

[image]

---

Ok now to solve the real problem(this must register at an emotional level) of if some triangle is actually an equilateral triangle, or scalene triangle or isosceles triangle or a right angle triangle.

To solve a problem, write down the functional logic involved in the problem

1. Equilateral triangle :- A triangle for which, all three sides are equal
2. Isosceles triangle :- A triangle for which, two of the three sides are equal
3. Scalene triangle :- A triangle for which, no sides are equal

Now think of the constraints

1. You can only use integers
2. Input sent as arguments

Now for writing the program since you're done analyzing

```
public class BufferProblem{
   public static void main(String[] args){ 
     int a, b, c;
     a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
     b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
     c = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

     if ((a == b) && (b == c)) { System.out.println("It is an equilateral triangle"); }
     else if (a == b || b == c || c == a) { System.out.println("It is an isosceles triangle"); }
     else if ((a != b) && (b != c) && (c != a)) { System.out.println("It is a scalene triangle");}

   }
}
```

Comment: I have already implemented similiar checks in my code. Btw, I have to use Linux and its Terminal. Okay, isn't there a way to put a restriction on top of my program like in C - define <largest integer to be accepted as input> = 2^31-1. If so, how to do it in Java (I am a novice)?